# Playwright fails to fill input

Tags: node.js, browser-automation, playwright

I'm running a Playwright script on a Jenkins page that has input elements. When I try to `fill` one of the inputs with text, it fails with this error:

```
(node:3337) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: page.fill: Protocol error (Page.insertText): error in channel "content::page": exception while running method "insertText" in namespace "page": Component returned failure code: 0xc1f30001 (NS_ERROR_NOT_INITIALIZED) [nsITextInputProcessor.commitCompositionWith] _insertText@chrome://juggler/content/content/PageAgent.js:891:32
```

I've tried running with `DEBUG=pw:api environment` enabled but the logs there aren't too helpful. From the normal console log I get the following log:

```
waiting for selector "input[name="_.buildNumber"]"
  selector resolved to visible <input value="" type="text" name="_.buildNumber" class=…/>
elementHandle.fill("54")
  waiting for element to be visible, enabled and editable
  element is visible, enabled and editable
```

So it seems like the element exists and can be edited but for some reason Playwright is unsuccessful at trying to fill it. What am I missing here?

Comment: I would create an issue on the github repo https://github.com/microsoft/playwright

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [Playwright bug](https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/5460) that is specific to Firefox. To get around it for now, you should be able to switch to using either Chrome or Safari in your import statement. So either:

```
import { chromium } from 'playwright';
```

Or using Safari:

```
import { webkit } from 'playwright';
```

Comment: not a solution if you need to test on firefox browsers